# Play Framework: how to deal with memory-intensive actions?

Tags: playframework, out-of-memory, pdfbox

I have a Play Framework application (Play 2.8, Scala 2.13 and Java 8) that creates JPG thumbnails from uploaded PDF files, using Apache PDFBox 2. The thumbnails are created upon request, then are cached on the file system. However, when one user tries to display the gallery with many PDFs for which no thumbnail is cached, a bunch of thumbnails are created simultaneously, and the server crashes with OutMemoryError (5 or 6 simultaneous tasks seems to be enough). The server restarts automatically and is available again after a few dozens of seconds, but the thumbnails that were being created are corrupt and I have to face many unavailabilities.

PDFBox is configured to use temp files, but the memory out occurs when the thumbnail image is being rendered.

The server has only 2 GB of RAM available. The uploaded PDFS are around 1 MB each and the generated thumbnails are around 100 KB (72 DPI; size is about 500×1000 px). Can I fix this problem without increasing the heap size? Ideally, Play should be able to queue these memory-intensive requests automatically, but I can live by restricting the number of simultaneous memory-intensive tasks manually, somehow…

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest version, and open separate PDDocument objects in each thread, and read this: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html

Comment: I don't know if it's possible in your case but for all of the generated content I would use a third party object store like AWS S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing probably would be to use a dedicated `ExecutionContext` with an underlying fixed size thread pool for generating the thumbnails.

```
import java.nio.file.Path
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

import scala.concurrent.{ ExecutionContext, Future }

object RenderPDF {
  implicit val ec : ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3 /* adjust */))

  def thumbnail(pdf: Path) : Future[Path] = Future {
    ... // call PDFbox
  }
}
```

You can use that in your action handler to load off the generation of the thumbnails.

It would be probably even better to pre-render the thumbnails in case you are dealing with uploaded PDFs, since that would avoid the problem of suddenly having to render dozens of PDFs if a user opens the gallery.

Comment: I actually used your later suggestion as a workaround. It would still cause problems if multiple users upload PDFs simultaneously, so I also implemented the your other solution.